# Webview is not accepting Cyrillic characters inside INPUT field

Tags: webview, android-webview, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

For some reason Android WebView is not accepting Cyrillic characters inside INPUT field. I have tried opening the same file with the default browser as well as Chrome on the phone and it has no problems with the Cyrillic. 
When I open the file inside the WebView, there is no problem typing in English, but as the moment you switch on Cyrillic it just stops accepting the letters.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

**UPDATE**

I have tried opening even https://stackoverflow.com inside webview and when you click on the search field for example and try to type in Cyrillic it will not work.